# Matplotlib interactive environment does not work

Tags: python, matplotlib, enthought

I am on OS X and using Encopy(by Enthought inc.) to write my python programs. The following code which I took it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5524858/matplotlib-show-doesnt-work-twice) only generates one point and then it terminates:

```
from pylab import *
import time
t = linspace(0.0, pi, 100)
x = cos(t)
y = sin(t)

ion()  # turn on interactive mode
figure(0)
subplot(111, autoscale_on=False, xlim=(-1.2, 1.2), ylim=(-.2, 1.2))

point = plot([x[0]], [y[0]], marker='o', mfc='r', ms=3)

for j in arange(len(t)):
    # reset x/y-data of point
    setp(point[0], data=(x[j], y[j]))
    time.sleep(0.05)
    draw() # redraw current figure

ioff() # turn off interactive mode
show()
```

Any Ideas what might be the problem?
And below is the photo of the result I get.[image]

Comment: use `plt.pause` instead of `sleep`

Comment: @tcaswell, Thanks. But still a single point!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is only plotting one point because you are only telling it to plot one point.  If you want to draw the line *up to* `j` use the following:

```
from pylab import *

t = linspace(0.0, pi, 100)
x = cos(t)
y = sin(t)
figure(0)
subplot(111, autoscale_on=False, xlim=(-1.2, 1.2), ylim=(-.2, 1.2))

point,  = plot([x[0]], [y[0]], marker='o', mfc='r', ms=3)

for j in arange(len(t)):
    # reset x/y-data of point
    point.set_data(x[:j], y[:j])
    plt.pause(0.05)
    plt.draw() # redraw current figure
```

Comment: Thanks a lot but what did you change that made the difference? I didn't quite get it!

Comment: @Naji I suggest you walk through the code by hand and look up what each function does.

Comment: What I can see is that you changed the point.set_data arguments. Well according to matplotlib's tutorial, setp is used to set the lines properties and I don't see anything wrong with that code. Plus there also another interesting thing with your code that you don't even change the interactive mode. How come??