# How do plt.plot(x,y) and plt.show() work the way they do?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I wanted to know the basic backbone process going on between `plt.plot(x,y)` and `plt.show()` commands of **matplotlib.pyplot**.

To elaborate it a bit, the piece of code:

```
plt.plot(x , y)
plt.show()
```

show the desired graph (no problem with that).

Also, the code:

```
plt.plot(x , y)
plt.plot(p , q)
plt.show()
```

works fine as well. **It shows the two plots created by the lists x & y and p & q.**

Now here is something that I found very interesting when coding dynamically in ipython.

```
In [73]: plt.plot(x , y)
#normal plotting function.
In [78]: plt.show()
#shows a graph as intended.
In [79]: plt.show()
#shows nothing.
```

Now, no matter how many times I call `plt.show()` (after I've called it once) it doesn't display the graph at all. **Why is so?**.

PS: To my understanding maybe there is an object being created and deleted withing this process. But neither I'm sure nor convinced.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suspect this is really a duplicate. You can save figures etc to reshow - once `show()` is done its done. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5524858/matplotlib-show-doesnt-work-twice

Comment: @doctorlove Yes I did stumbled upon the hyperlinked question question before posting my question. I wanted to know how(and if possible why) this happens. I do understand that once `show()` is called it's done. The question is *how it is done*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pyplot uses or is a so called "statemachine". It stores a number of figures and references to the current axes and figure. Once `show` is called, all figures are shown and once `show` returns, they are removed from the statemachine.

On a subsequent call to `show` there are no figures to show anymore, hence not output is shown.

Therefore there is some (maybe unwritten or implicit) assumption that `show` is called exactly once in a script.

It may be worth noting that although figures are removed from the statemachine they remain in memory until they are closed. So they may be reused under certain circumstances and depending on the desired workflow.

Comment: According to a quote from the linked topic, it was explicitly coded with the intention of it being called once, as the last line in a script.

Comment: So is this statemachine behavior controlled by creating and deleting objects or is this(statemachine) concept something completely different?

Comment: Internally there for sure objects created. As said, they are not deleted but rather removed from some kind of collection.

Comment: Okay. I'll read more about this statemachine type of working. Thanks a lot.